# Performance issues with Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++

For some reason, Notepad++ has performance issues when I open a file containing a very long line (+40M characters).

The total size of the file is approximately 60 MB. I have to wait several seconds each time I move the cursor.

Is there a time consuming option I should disable? No syntax highlighting is enabled.

Comment: Try toggling line wrapping and see if it helps.   I think the biggest problem is simply attempting to measure the line width for the horizontal scrollbar.  The Scintilla editing component that N++ (and many other editors) use simply doesn't consider extremely long lines to be a worthwhile use case to optimize performance for.

Answer (score 1):

60 MB is quite a big size for a text editor .
It will take some time to open such a large file and there is no other way to speedup this process

Comment: I becomes a lot faster if you disable line breaks and syntax colouring, but even then rendering the text takes quite some time.

Comment: As a side note, this was the reason I switched to Sublime Text. It was able to open larger file sizes without freezing nor affecting other documents on other tabs.